# How to enter system motherboard BIOS at boot up when using Logitech K780 keyboard

Tags: boot, bios, logitech-keyboard

Is it possible to enter the system motherboard BIOS at boot up when using Logitech K780 keyboard? If so, what key(s) need to be pressed?

Comment: The keyboard doesn't matter. The key to use is a function of your motherboard. What are your computer model and motherboard model?

Comment: It's a machine I built up with a Gigabyte Z270M-D3H MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering the BIOS/UEFI can be done with any functioning keyboard.

The Gigabyte official for entering it is <kbd>Del</kbd>.
Pressing it once should be enough if pressed at the right time.
If you're not sure of finding the right-time, you may press it more
than once.

Reference :
[Chapter 2 Bios Setup; Startup Screen - Gigabyte GA-Z270M-D3H User Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2712947/Gigabyte-Ga-Z270m-D3h.html?page=19).